# Unable to see my SFP connection using ifconfig

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet, connection, ifconfig

When I do ifconfig, below is the output, I have the virbr0,virbr1..., and also the vnet 0 - 20. Not sure why I have this, because I just got this server few days ago. I inserted the SFP cable and I can see the lights are blinking but no eth is showing on ifconfig. I run 'lspci | grep Ether' and I can see the SFP port.

`ifconfig`

[image]

[image]

`lspci |grep Ether`

[image]

Comment: Try to check the interface status by `sudo ethtool <Ethernet_interface_name>`. Do it for all physical interfaces to verify which are active. Search for these lines: `Speed:  `, `Duplex:  ` and `Link detected:  `. Did you install the drivers for network cards?

Comment: Use `lshw | grep -i -C 5 "ether"` and search for interface name in line with the `logical name:` string. Then use `ethtool` mentioned above.